# Kafka Connect Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition could be determined

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am facing Consumer timeout when using Kafka Connect. But if I use Kafka Console Consumer there are no errors.

> [2020-06-24 14:54:37,750] ERROR [Consumer
> clientId=connector-consumer-simple-elasticsearch-connector-0,
> groupId=connect-simple-elasticsearch-connector] User provided listener
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance failed
> on invocation of onPartitionsAssigned for partitions
> [simple.elasticsearch.data-dev-0]
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:298)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms
> expired before the position for partition
> simple.elasticsearch.data-dev-0 could be determined [2020-06-24
> 14:54:37,751] ERROR
> WorkerSinkTask{id=simple-elasticsearch-connector-0} Task threw an
> uncaught and unrecoverable exception
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms
> expired before the position for partition
> simple.elasticsearch.data-dev-0 could be determined [2020-06-24
> 14:54:37,752] ERROR
> WorkerSinkTask{id=simple-elasticsearch-connector-0} Task is being
> killed and will not recover until manually restarted
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:188) [2020-06-24
> 14:54:37,752] INFO Stopping ElasticsearchSinkTask.
> (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask:185)

Comment: I have found the issue! It was a mismatch between Kafka Server and Kafka Connect. I was using Kafka-2.2 with Kafka-connect-2.7. After I changed it to 2.2 it worked like Magic!